# Как отсылать "multipart/form-data" через python с помощью requests?

Tags: python, requests

Запрос формируется подобным образом:

```
-----------------------------40338331074230303145107977467
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

что-то
-----------------------------40338331074230303145107977467
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="token"


-----------------------------40338331074230303145107977467--
```

Как можно отослать такой запрос?

Comment: По-моему, через функцию post через атрибут `data`, в который словарь передается

Comment: @gil9red, Пробовал, не вышло

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12385179/10941639.

Comment: Подебажить можно тут: https://webhook.site

Comment: @XXX, попробуйте, как было предложено в ссылке выше, через `files` отправлять. Кст, вот пример логирования запросов от requests: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8c229fa87043169523adc4187a544237e6a4c9ca/requests__examples/debug_logging__requests.py#L10, так сможете убедиться, что запрос правильно формируется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Формы “multipart/form-data” отправляются в параметре `files`. В вашем случае:

```
requests.post(
    'http://requestb.in/xucj9exu',
    files=(
        ('name', (None, 'что-то')),
        ('token', (None, '')),
    )
)
```